# Widget is not being animated in Kivy

Tags: animation, kivy

I am trying to animate an image with button behavior across the screen. I got the animation to work before with the exact same code (at least for the animation part) so I would assume the code for the animation does what I want it to do, but after making some changes it no longer works. It calls to self.to_menu() when clicked but no animation takes place. What am I doing wrong?

start_screen.py

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
from functools import partial
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
import time


presentation = Builder.load_file("test.kv")

def set_color(button, color, *args):
    button.color = color






class PStartButton(ButtonBehavior, Image, Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(PStartButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        #Clock.schedule_interval(self.reset_color, 3)

    def reset_color(self, *args):
            Clock.schedule_once(partial(set_color, self, (1,1,1,1)),1)

            Clock.schedule_once(partial(set_color, self, (0,1,0,1)),2)


    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos): 
            Clock.unschedule(self.reset_color)

            self.to_menu()


    #def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        #if self.collide_point(*touch.pos): 
        #if touch.grab_current is self:
            #self.to_menu()
            #return True

    def to_menu(self):
        #sb=self.ids.pstart_button
        anim = Animation(pos =(Window.width * .05, Window.height *.60))
        anim &= Animation(size =(Window.width * .15, Window.height * .15))
        anim.start(self)

class StartScreen(FloatLayout):

    pass

    #def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        #super(StartScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)





runTouchApp(StartScreen())
```

test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.9
<StartScreen>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    size: root.size
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos:self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'bg.png'
    FloatLayout:

        PStartButton:
            id:pstart_button
            pos: root.center_x - (self.width/2), root.center_y - (self.height/2)


<FloatLayout>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'

<PStartButton>:

    size_hint: (.30,.30)

    source: 'start_button.png'
```

Comment: In case you are still interested: I came across a problem that is perhaps related and found a helpful answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34879319/animation-doest-work-as-expected-for-widget-object-in-kivy. The position and size of the widget have to be specified before the animation starts. Maybe that is not any longer the case after you changed your code.